# Jupyter Note pandas scatter_matrix

Tags: python, pandas

Hi the problem is that the Jupyter note tells me pandas does not have the attribute 'scatter_matrix'.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns =iris_dataset.feature_names)
grr=pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15,15), marker='o',
                  hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up because `scatter_matrix` is an attribute of `pandas.plotting` and not `pandas`. See you have `pandas` and `scatter_matrix` imported. You can either use:

```
grr=pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,c=y_train,figsize(15,15),marker='o',hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

or

```
grr=scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,c=y_train,figsize(15,15),marker='o',hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```